# Recommendation to share outgoing email attachments via Sharepoint on Office 365?

Tags: sharing, outlook, microsoft-exchange, email-attachments

We are facing the common problem that our colleagues need to distribute large files < 25 MB. They used Outlook for that. It's not optimal, but it got the job done in 99 out of 100 cases.

Now with the migration to Office 365 we will hit the limit of 25 MB quite often. I am looking for a software (Outlook addin?), that does the following:

- Integrates with Office 365, Exchange Online and Outlook 2013 client
- Outlook: detect attachments bigger than a definable size
- Outlook/Sharepoint: Store the attachment on Sharepoint Online and make it publicly accessible with a secret address (similar to Googles and Microsoft file-share via link)
- Outlook: Remove the attachment from the mail and replace it with a hyperlink to the file stored in Sharepoint.

Looking forward to your recommendations.